# Where can i find out the "Convert to Web Application" option in Visual studio 2010 Premium

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-applications

Where can i find out the "Convert to Web Application" option in Visual studio 2010 Premium version.I have a website which i want to convert to Web application.I right clicked on the project int the solution explorer and could'nt see that in the context menu.I have Power commands extension installed too.

Answer (score -1):

I use MS Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate which has all of the features of Premium, I also see that this menu is missing.
I suggest that you make a new ASP.NET web application with the same name and copy the resources of the Website to the resource folder of the web application, and load the resources as existing items.